# Hammerjs 2.0.2 swipe detection not working

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I just started using hammerjs for my recent project and with the [latest version](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/)

This is how do i am detecting the `swipeLeft` event:

```
var block = document.getElementById('om_hammer');
var hammertime = new Hammer( block );
hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
hammertime.on('swipeleft', function(e){
    console.log('in');
});
```

But nothing happens. I tried checking if the object is initialized correctly with `console.log(hammertime);` and it displays the applied event and element.

I am debugging it in chrome (Emulator) but there are no error messages. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please name the version for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

I digg little more research and got the solution even still don't know if it is the right way or not.

```
    var block = document.getElementById('om_hammer');
    var move, start, end;
    var hammertime = new Hammer( document.body );
    hammertime.add(new Hammer.Swipe({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }));
    hammertime.add(new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }));

    hammertime.on('panstart', function(e){
        move = e.direction;
        start = e.distance;
    });
    hammertime.on('panend', function(e){
        move = e.direction;
        end = e.distance;
        var totalDistance = end - start;

        hammerInit(move, end);
    });
```

I detect the pan motion and did the staff that i want. Not yet tested on the mobile device yet just with the chorme emulator console.